# What are the network prerequisites for Windows Azure Pack

Tags: networking, sql-server, virtual-machines, azure

I have followed [many articles to install and config](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=install%20windows%20azure%20pack) windows azure pack distributed, But every time I finish configuring everything, the azure pack is not working and give me different errors, seams to me there is a network prerequisites I should config first before setting up the servers, for example to keep all server on the same azure network, but I couldn't find anyone mentioning this.

So my question is:
Does just setting up different servers and make them all connect to the same sql server is enough? or there are some network configurations I should do as well?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many things that are off, like DNS, networking settings etc. 
A couple of MVP's created a WAP Wiki and OneNote that is a must read when you start implementing azure (pack)  http://www.hyper-v.nu/archives/hvredevoort/2015/01/azure-pack-wiki-available-via-onenote/ 
Hope that provides some useful pointers.

The official place for the prerequisites should be this one https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296442.aspx

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit on the content of the url's, to make this answer a bit more self-contained and less reliant on the links provided it would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the tip @Reaces, being a newbie here, I will make sure there's either more context, or no links in my future answers. If all servers are (distributed) in the same subnet, that should not be a problem for an Azure Pack deployment.

Comment: You can always edit your current question, and put some explanation in there. I'm sure there are people here who will gladly up-vote a decent answer made better with context.